# Appending an item into an array inside a struct

Tags: solidity, arrays, function

Working on solidity 8.12, I have two structs, namely `singer` and `event`, two arrays one for singers and another for events. I want to write down a function that creates an event, specifying the singer id, and automatically append the event id into the array of events attended by the singer:

```
struct Singer {
uint id;
uint[] events_ids; // THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO UPDATE WITH THE NEW EVENT ID
}

struct Event {
uint id;
uint singer_id;
}

singer[] public SingerList;
event[] public EventList;
uint public n_singers;
uint public n_events;

    function CreateEvent(uint singer_id) external {
        if (singer_id > n_singers) { // singer id greater than the number of current singers.
            revert SingerIdError(singer_id);
        }
        else if (singer_id == n_singers){ // the singer does not exist yet! Create it!
            n_singers ++;
-------->   SingerList.push(Singer(singer_id))); // HOW TO APPEND THE EVENT ID TO THE LIST OF EVENTS IN SINGER STRUCT?
            EventList.push(Event(n_events, singer_id));
            
        }

        else { // the pilot already exists
            Singer storage _singer = SingerList[singer_id];
            _singer.event_ids.push(n_events);
            EventList.push(Event(n_events, n_events));
        }
        n_events ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Singer storage singer = singerList.push();
singer.id = singer_id;
singer.event_ids.push(n_events);
```

in the first line the push function is used to add a singer to the singerList

from the [doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/types.html?highlight=array%20push#array-members):

> push() ... It returns a reference to the element

that reference stored in the singer variable is used to set the id and event_ids to the singer added to the list